# Wrapping async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a strange behaviour concerning wrapping asynchronous methods in C#.

It is difficult to cut out the portion of my code that has this strange behaviour, so instead I made a test project to investigate the behaviour, and this is what I have found out.

I have a test class which has an async method that is simply a wrapper of another async method: (In my original code it is a wrapper class which contains 2 objects, which it has wrapper methods for)

```
public class Test
{
    public async Task Delay()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

In my test program I am running the following code from an async event handler: (In my case the Loaded event, since I am using a WPF Window)

```
var test = new Test();
await Task.Delay(1000);
await test.Delay();
Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
test.Delay().Wait();
```

All is well until the last line, which never returns.

Then I tried changing the test class to the following and the last line works:

```
public class Test
{
    public Task Delay()
    {
        return Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

My question is why the first scenario does not work?

Comment: this is not "overloading"

Comment: You might be right (it was the best term that I could think of), but could you please supply a better term then?

Comment: +1: Good point, I am editing the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By *default* the `await` keyword is built to try to keep as much of the original code as possible running on the original thread (or, at least, in the same "context" as the code that runs before the `await`, e.g. if you were running in the thread pool previously, any thread pool thread will do).

What's happening is that all of your original code, when it can run, wants to run on the UI thread.

But you're blocking the UI thread in that `Wait` so it's never available to run the remainder of the code inside your `async` method and so complete the outer `Task`. I.e. there's just this little bit of code left to run in your method, after the `Task.Delay` task has completed:

```
public class Test
{
    public async Task Delay()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        //<-- This "Code" needs to run before my Task is completed
    }
}
```

---

You can use [`ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait(v=vs.110).aspx) to request that this not happen:

> *continueOnCapturedContext*
>
> **true** to attempt to marshal the continuation back to the original context captured; otherwise, **false**.

---

See also this old [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx) by Eric Lippert, from when `async` was new:

> The “async” modifier on the method does not mean “this method is automatically scheduled to run on a worker thread asynchronously”. It means the **opposite** of that; it means “this method contains control flow that involves awaiting asynchronous operations and will therefore be rewritten by the compiler into continuation passing style to ensure that the asynchronous operations can resume this method at the right spot.” **The whole point of async methods it that you stay on the current thread as much as possible.**

Comment: The desirable solution here is not to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, but rather to not wait on the async operation.

Comment: I can see your point in that, so would you rather use the second scenario of not marking it async and returning the Task of the called async method? But then what if I wanted to call multiple async methods?

Comment: @reSPAWNed The correct solution is described in Stephen's answer, not this one.  You should make the entire application asynchronous, and not mix asynchronous and synchronous methods.  If you do that, you won't have this problem at all.

Comment: @Servy: That is a valid point, but then why is there even a Wait method, if it is wrong to mix asynchronous and synchronous code? Or put in another way, in what scenario would one use the Wait method?

Comment: @reSPAWNed It's primarily a relic of the fact that the first iteration of `Task` was primarily there to represent CPU bound work performed in a thread pool thread.  It's definition has since expanded to represent any asynchronous operation.  Tasks can sometimes be used in applications that don't really leverage asynchronous at all, and do their waiting entirely synchronously, throughout the application.  The point is that you can do one or the other, you just shouldn't mix and match.

Comment: @reSPAWNed - you put a `Wait` in when there's nothing else that your current thread could usefully be doing. This is only, generally, when you "own" the thread you're running on. The UI thread can usually find other useful things to do, as can thread pool threads, so *generally* you wouldn't put a `Wait` in either of them.

Answer (score 5):

I describe this deadlock scenario in detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and in an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

By default, when you `await` a task, it will capture the current "context" (`SynchronizationContext.Current` unless it is `null`, in which case it captures `TaskScheduler.Current`). When the `async` method resumes, it resumes in that context.

In your case, the UI context is captured, and your `async` method is attempting to resume on the UI thread after the delay completes. However, it cannot resume execution because the UI thread is blocked waiting for the task to complete.

The best solution is to use `async` "all the way"; in other words, don't block on `async` code.